# How to group more than one key using Map/Reduce with MongoDB? Emitting more than one key?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my Rails 3.2 project, I'm using MongoDB (Mongoid) to group some results using map/reduce, something like:

```
  def count_and_group_by(context)
    raise "No #{context} attribute" unless %w(action browser country).include? context

    map = %Q{
      function() {
        key = this.#{context};
        value = {count: 1};
        emit(key, value);
      }
    }

    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {
        var reducedValue = {count: 0};
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          reducedValue.count += value.count; 
        });
        return reducedValue;
      }
    }

    map_reduce = self.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)

    Hash[map_reduce.map {|v| [v["_id"],v["value"]["count"].to_i]}]
  end
```

Once I use the method with something like `MyClass.count_and_group_by("action")`, I get the results with the following format:

```
{"change_password"=>31, "invalid_ip"=>32, "login_failure"=>74, "login_success"=>63, "logout"=>34}
```

Now what I do usually, is trying to group results based on an attribute, like to find results based on *action* attribute, *browser* and *city* attributes, and I do that separately with a new call for each, like: `MyClass.count_and_group_by("action")`, `MyClass.count_and_group_by("browser")`, `MyClass.count_and_group_by("city")`.

Is there anyway to emit more than one key a time so I can group results at once and get results something like:

```
{"action" => { 
  "change_password"=>31, 
  "invalid_ip"=>32, 
  "login_failure"=>74, 
  "login_success"=>63, 
  "logout"=>34},
 "browser" => {}
 "city" => {}}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should generally be possible, but really for this type of operation you would get more performance out of using the aggregation framework instead. There is not presently an "aggregate" method on the classes defined with Mongoid, but there is a `.collection` accessor which exposes the underlying driver object. So you can call [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) from here:

```
result = this.collection.aggregate([

    # Include each field and an array for "type" in all documents
    { "$project" => {
        "action" => 1,
        "browser" => 1,
        "country" => 1,
        "type" => { "$const" => [ "action", "browser", "country" ] },
    }},

    # Unwind that "type" array
    { "$unwind" => "$type" },

    # Group by "type" and the values of each field which matches
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => {
            "type" => "$type",
            "value" => {
                "$cond" => [
                    { "$eq" => [ "$type", "action" ] },
                    "$action",
                    { "$cond" => [ 
                        { "$eq" => [ "$type", "browser" ] },
                        "$browser",
                        "$country"
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }},

    # Just in case all fields were not present in all documents
    { "$match" => { "_id.value" => { "$ne" => null } } },

    # Group to a single document with each "type" as the keys
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => null,
        "action" => { 
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "action" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       },
       "browser" => {
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "browser" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       },
       "country" => {
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "country" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       }
   }},

   # Filter out any null values from the conditional allocation
   { "$project" => {
       "action" => { "$setDifference" => [ "$action", [null] ] },
       "browser" => { "$setDifference" => [ "$browser", [null] ] },
       "country" => { "$setDifference" => [ "$country", [null] ] }
   }}
])
```

That makes use of a newer MongoDB 2.6 introduced [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator in order to filter any null values out of the resulting arrays. The same thing can be done with prior versions with little impact on the processing, just more steps:

```
result = this.collection.aggregate([

    # Include each field and an array for "type" in all documents
    { "$project" => {
        "action" => 1,
        "browser" => 1,
        "country" => 1,
        "type" => { "$const" => [ "action", "browser", "country" ] },
    }},

    # Unwind that "type" array
    { "$unwind" => "$type" },

    # Group by "type" and the values of each field which matches
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => {
            "type" => "$type",
            "value" => {
                "$cond" => [
                    { "$eq" => [ "$type", "action" ] },
                    "$action",
                    { "$cond" => [ 
                        { "$eq" => [ "$type", "browser" ] },
                        "$browser",
                        "$country"
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }},

    # Just in case all fields were not present in all documents
    { "$match" => { "_id.value" => { "$ne" => null } } },

    # Group to a single document with each "type" as the keys
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => null,
        "action" => { 
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "action" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       },
       "browser" => {
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "browser" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       },
       "country" => {
           "$addToSet" => {
               "$cond" => [
                   { "$eq" => [ "$_id.type", "country" ] },
                   { "value" => "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                   null
               ]
           }
       }
   }},

   # Filter out any null values from the conditional allocation
   { "$unwind": "$country" },
   { "$match": { "country": { "$ne": null } } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "action": { "$first": "$action" },
       "browser": { "$first": "$browser" },
       "country": { "$push": "$country" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$browser" },
   { "$match": { "browser": { "$ne": null } } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "action": { "$first": "$action" },
       "browser": { "$push": "$browser" },
       "country": { "$first": "$country" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$action" },
   { "$match": { "action": { "$ne": null } } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "action": { "$push": "$action" },
       "browser": { "$first": "$browser" },
       "country": { "$first": "$country" }
   }}
])
```

The output is a little different to the key/value form, but can easily be manipulated into one with much the same post processing as you are presently doing. So with input such as this:

```
{ "action" : "change_password", "browser" : "ie", "country" : "US" }
{ "action" : "change_password", "browser" : "ie", "country" : "UK" }
{ "action" : "change_password", "browser" : "chrome", "country" : "AU" }
```

The results obtained are like this:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "action" : [
        {
            "value" : "change_password",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "browser" : [
        {
            "value" : "ie",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "value" : "chrome",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "country" : [
        {
            "value" : "US",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "value" : "UK",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "value" : "AU",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So you have a bit of difference in the output to mapReduce, but then again any mapReduce output would also be "not exactly" how you want the output format anyhow. Being implemented in native code, the aggregation framework runs much faster